# why the series give me zscore of NAN when series data are not constant

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, normalization, nan

I have a question regarding to z-score in python. I plan to calculate an coounting ratio-GPOA and generating its z-score values in the form of series.
Here is what I did:

```
 #Profitablity
    # GPOA
    gpoa=(ccm_['revt']-ccm_['cogs'])/ccm_['at']
    gpoa=np.array(gpoa)
    gpoa_z=stats.zscore(gpoa)
    print (gpoa)
    print(gpoa_z)
```

Here is the output:

```
[ 0.09561083  0.09561083  0.09561083 ...,  0.02845481  0.00311008  0.        ]
[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
```

the first several data gave NAN, I can understand. It was because the data is constant so standard deviation is zero, hence cannot be parameter, and resulted in NAN. But as you can see the following data is not constant anymore, the z-score is still NAN.

Update 1:

I changed the gpoa from `series` to `array`, and then apply `stats.zcore`, still does not work.

Update 2:

```
#Profitablity
# GPOA
gpoa=(ccm_['revt']-ccm_['cogs'])/ccm_['at']
gpoa=np.array(gpoa, dtype=pd.Series)
gpoa_mean=np.mean(gpoa)
gpoa_std=np.std(gpoa)
gpoa_z=(gpoa-gpoa_mean)/gpoa_std
print(gpoa_z)
```

Still not working. The output is as follows:

```
[nan nan nan ..., nan nan nan]
```

my gpoa_mean is a `inf`and it is already float64.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Test for the existence of `nan` in `gpoa` with, for example, `print(np.isnan(gpoa).any())`.  If that prints `True`, you have a `nan` in your input array.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser- hello, as you see, gpoa is calculated from revt, cogs and at. One step prior to this one was that I filled all missing data within these three columns with the mean value of its residual non-missing values. So that in revt, cogs, at, there is no nan.

Comment: OK, but maybe you can humor me and check anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser-Yes I will definitely check it. And I will let you know:)))

Comment: Hold on... you say `gpoa_mean` is `inf`?!  That means you have the value `inf` in `gpoa`, and that will also cause the z-score to be `nan`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser so how can I check if there is any inf in the series? now it's a series, do I have to change to array and then check??

Comment: For a numpy array, you can use [`numpy.isinf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html) or [`numpy.isfinite`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html).  I think you can pass a Pandas `Series` to these function, or you can convert the `Series` to a numpy array first.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser-ok I will let you know how it works thank youso much!!!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I just checked using the code you give me, there is no inf in my series since it returns [False,False,False...False, False,False]

Comment: That shows six values are False.  What about the values hidden in `...`?  Did you try `np.any(np.isinf(gpoa))`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser-yes there is inf data in gpoa. and we use gpoa.replace(np.inf,(gpoa.mean()). But this cannot kill all inf data, there are still inf data there, we checked.

Comment: `gpoa.replace(np.inf,(gpoa.mean())` won't work, because if `inf` occurs in `gpoa`, then `gpoa.mean()` is `inf`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser so my goal is to replace all inf or nan into the mean of the remaining data. Is there any method?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `nan_policy='omit'` option in `stats.zscore`. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.zscore.html).

```
gpoa_z=stats.zscore(gpoa, nan_policy='omit')
```